# Sqlite en Unity para Android

Tags: android, c#, sqlite, unity

Estoy desarrollando un .APK en Unity, donde tengo una BD en `SQLite`.

Al hacer pruebas dentro del entorno de Unity todo funciona perfectamente, pero a la hora de exportarlo a `.APK`y probarlo en mi teléfono, tras ejecutar 2 consultas seguidas el programa "se bloquea" lo pongo entre comillas ya que la interfaz sigue respondiendo.

Codigo SQLite de la consulta;

```
public bool UsuarioCorrecto(string nombre, string contra)
{
    int code = 0;

    using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection(connection))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"select nombre from Usuarios where nombre like @nombre and contrasena like @contrasena";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@nombre", nombre));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@contrasena", contra));
            using (SqliteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    code = 1;
                }
                else { code = 0; }
            }
        }
    }

    if (code == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Codigo para autentificar a un usuario;

```
public void deleteUltimaCon()
{
    using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection(connection))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"delete from ultimaCon";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

public void Conectar_Click()
{
    if (conectarDB())
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        dialog.showDialog("Usuario correcto!");
        #endif
        db.deleteUltimaCon();
        db.anadirUltCon(nombre.text);
        MensajeConectar.text = "Exito..";
        ProjectVars.Instance.StringActiveBetweenScenes = nombre.text;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("menJugador");
    }
    else
    {
        mostrarTextAut();
        MensajeConectar.text = "Fallo de autentificación";
        Invoke("ocultarTextAut", 1.5f);
    }
}
```

Haciendo pruebas con mensajes la ejecución se queda en la linea donde dice `db.deleteUltimaCon();`

¿Como podría solucionarlo para que la aplicación no se quede "colgada"?

Comment: Por un lado...no veo que cierres la conexión con la base de datos (aunque al estar en un `using` tal vez debería cerrarse al salir del bloque). Por otro..has revisado el logcat para ver que error te da?

Comment: Si el tema de hacer `con.Close()` lo he probado y el resultado es el mismo, a la hora de depurar en Unity, no salta ningún tipo de error, y en el teléfono no lo he podido debuguear.

Comment: Hay aplicaciones en la play store que te permiten acceder al logcat, donde debería verse el error que te está lanzando... .Tambien conectando el movil a tu pc y, por ejemplo desde android studio, puedes acceder al logcat en tiempo real

Comment: [Aqui](https://answers.unity.com/questions/492681/how-to-use-adb-logcat.html) te explican tambien como depurar una apk unity con adb.

Comment: Muchas gracias me pongo a ello.

Comment: De todas maneras, también sería bueno que añadieras a tu pregunta el código de `deleteUltimaCon` por si pudiera dar una pista.

Comment: @Pikoh en realidad el tipo de consulta da igual, ya que sucede lo mismo en cualquier parte de la aplicacion donde se ejecuten 2 sentencias seguidas, en otra parte donde se registra el usuario primero consulta a la BD que ese nuevo usuario no existe y luego lo añade, realizando las 2 acciones pero no imprimiendo el mensaje que está tras la consulta de añadir.

Comment: En ese caso, el problema tiene toda la pinta de que es porque la conexión queda en un estado incorrecto y no puedes reutilizarla (algo del tipo `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException`). Yo probaría a meter el `con.close` en todos los sitios por si acaso.Otra opción es que uses una sola conexión para toda la aplicación, es posible que eso resuelva el problema.

Comment: @Pikoh he creado una unica instancia de conexión para todas las escenas y al mismo tiempo cierro todas las conexiones, el resultado es el mismo, luego miraré con calma el tema de debuguear en Android, gracias por las sugerencias :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucioné el problema cambiando todas las consultas y la manera de acceder a la BD dejo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864346/using-populated-sqlite-database-in-android-via-unity) el sitio de donde obtuve toda la información.